# Can I delete all cache pool from Symfony's controller?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using Symfony 4.4 and memcached. I have created cache pool in which I am storing similar data with different keys. After HTTP request I want to delete all cache. Is it possible to do that with some method?

```php
class ContactsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $contactsCache;

    public function __construct(
      CacheInterface $contactsCache
    ){

        $this->contactsCache = $contactsCache;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => ['renewCache', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE]
        ];
    }

    public function renewCache(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
        $contact = $event->getControllerResult();

        if (!$contact instanceof Contact && $method === Request::METHOD_GET) {
            return;
        }

        $this->contactsCache->delete('cache1');
        $this->contactsCache->delete('cache2');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cache class `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter` inherits from `AbstractAdapter`that implements `ResettableInterface`.

This interface when implemented adds a `reset()` method.

Maybe changing `CacheInterface` to `ResettableInterface` will do the job. (I can't test)